# Unable to make a request to AWS S3 multi-region access point with .NET AWS SDK (Unity)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I am trying to access AWS multi region access point using S3 SDK, but have this error when making request:

> MarshalDirectiveException: Marshalling of non-string and non-blittable
> arrays to managed code is not implemented. (wrapper native-to-managed)
> Aws.Crt.Auth.AwsSigner.OnHttpRequestSigningComplete(ulong,int,intptr,ulong,intptr,intptr,unit)

Here is the code:

```
Config = new AmazonS3Config();

Config.UseArnRegion = false;
Config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest2;
                
Client = new AmazonS3Client(Config);
        
GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest
{                   
    BucketName = arn:aws:s3::123456789012:accesspoint/<MRAP_alias>,
    Key = filename                    
};

Client.GetObjectAsync(req).Wait();
```

Everything works fine when I make a request to the bucket directly or when I use CLI.

It seems that the problem could be with the .NET version. I tested it with .NET Core 3.1 and it worked, but the project is made on Unity, and Unity is limited to .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET Framework 4.x

Current versions:
AWSSDK.Core.3.7.13.12 AWSSDK.S3.3.7.9.61 AWSSDK.Extensions.CrtIntegration.3.7.1.4

Comment: I think this might be a bug, I'd recommend filing a bug report here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues